# What can be used to replace tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, version, optimizer-statistics

I'm trying to convert my TensorFlow 1.4 code to TensorFlow 2 but in there's no more `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` in TF 2.

What should be the replacement for tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer?

I found the same thing in `tf.compat.v1.train.` but I shouldn't use it as those stuff in `tf.compat` will be removed sooner or later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace it with, `tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()` defined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD).
[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/migration_guide#keras_optimizers) (skip to third point) is the official message, where TF team mentioned to use this keras optimizer.

Comment: tks, i will use this sgd, but hm, TF is looking more and more like keras

Comment: Yes, but this brings many advantages too like it is easier to understand, implement, manipulate with same functionality. Cheers!